# Calculating OKX LOT Size Using CCXT

Tags: python, ccxt

I just started using CCXT few days ago. Just wondering if there's any easy or direct way to calculate future lot size on OKX or do I have to calculate it manually?

For example,
Is there any API which can take the available USDT as an input and give the max lot size in return?

Currently I'm doing something like this,

```
def fetch_order_qty(symbol):
    
    leverage = 10

    balance_req = okx.fetchBalance()
    balance = balance_req['free']['USDT']
    ticker_req = okx.fetchTicker(symbol)
    ticker_cost = ticker_req['bid']

    # risking 10% of the available capital
    trade_capital = 10/100*balance
    
    ticker_qty = (trade_capital / ticker_cost) * leverage * lot_multiplier
    return ticker_qty

print(fetch_order_qty('BTC-USDT-SWAP'))
```

But every symbol got different kind of lots. So is there any ways to calculate it. Or is there a way to just directly buy the order using USDT margin amount without mentioning any LOT quantity using CCXT (OKX) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import ccxt

print('CCXT Version:', ccxt.__version__)

exchange = ccxt.okx()
markets = exchange.load_markets()
lot_size = exchange.market('BTC-USDT-SWAP')['precision']['amount']

print(lot_size)
```

---

there's also `exchange.market('BTC-USDT-SWAP')['contractSize']` which sounds like it might be something you want